# Best Practice to avoid Angular Version Conflict

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

This diagram explains my question ---->
[Version Conflict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywkWj.jpg)

My product takes a dependency on a node package, which takes a dependency on a certain version of Angular, lets say version #y.

However, my product relies on a different version of Angular - lets say version #x.

I cannot ensure that #x = #y.

What is the best way to avoid such version conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

If your dependency is for e.g. Angular X.Y and your angular version is X, compatibility problems shouldn't arise, but you can use `npm shrinkwrap` functionality which will allow you to lockdown version of dependencies.

It will generate `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "A",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "B": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "from": "B@^1.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/B/-/B-1.0.1.tgz",
      "dependencies": {
        "C": {
          "version": "1.0.1",
          "from": "org/C#v1.0.1",
          "resolved": "git://github.com/org/C.git#5c380ae319fc4efe9e7f2d9c78b0faa588fd99b4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about it [here](http://%7B%20%20%20%22name%22:%20%22A%22,%20%20%20%22version%22:%20%221.1.0%22,%20%20%20%22dependencies%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22B%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22version%22:%20%221.0.1%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22from%22:%20%22B@%5E1.0.0%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22resolved%22:%20%22https://registry.npmjs.org/B/-/B-1.0.1.tgz%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22dependencies%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22C%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22version%22:%20%221.0.1%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22from%22:%20%22org/C#v1.0.1%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22resolved%22:%20%22git://github.com/org/C.git#5c380ae319fc4efe9e7f2d9c78b0faa588fd99b4%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%7D%20%7D).